# Angular 2 component not working

Tags: angular

I'm just staring Angular and have a simple angular component (the glyphicon glyphicon-star you see on the left in stack over flow questions) which i want to display but I can only get a non clickable star .

here is my code:
favorite.component.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'favorite',
    template: `    
 <i 
        class="glyphicon"
        [class.glyphicon-star-empty] ="!isFavorite"
        [class.glyphicon-star]="isFavorite"
        (click)="onClick()">
    </i>
    `
})
export class FavoriteComponent { 
    isFavorite = false;

    onclick() {
        this.isFavorite = !this.isFavorite;
    }
}
```

In app.component I'm trying to render this 'favorite' component:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {CoursesComponent} from './courses.component'
import {AuthorsComponent} from './authors.component'
import {FavoriteComponent} from './favorite.component'



@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1><courses></courses><authors></authors><button class ="btn btn-primary">Submit</button><br><favorite></favorite>',
    directives: [CoursesComponent, AuthorsComponent] 
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

How do I render the component in my app.component ?

Full code here : https://github.com/aindriu80/Angular2withTypeScript

The code doesn't load up the component - i only get the favorite favorite
[image: F12 View Source Chrome]

Comment: can you show also your module definition

Comment: i myself new into angular2, however in many tutorial they tend to have their app.module to list the component you wanted to use and bootstrap the module in the main.ts file by importing platformbrowserdynamic

Comment: what do you mean the module definition ? I just have one componet favorite.component.ts the typescrpypt

Comment: i suggest that you create a favorite.html and insert your template in there and pass the template url instead of the template.  Make sure you reference the path from the web route like `templateUrl: client/favorite.html`

Comment: I have the full code Im working on in github -  if you go to the link above and select commits - then favorite initial and download that version thats all the files.

Comment: Man, you are using Angular2 BETA version.  I suggest you to use stable version at least 2.0.0. It will be easier for you to find help

Comment: im going to move to stable once i finish learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.  I had a missing directive in my app.components.ts file.  Thanks for pointing out the case sensitivity.

app.component.ts

```
    import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {CoursesComponent} from './courses.component'
import {AuthorsComponent} from './authors.component'
import {FavoriteComponent} from './favorite.component'



@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1><courses></courses><authors></authors><button class ="btn btn-primary">Submit</button><br><favorite></favorite>',
    directives: [CoursesComponent, AuthorsComponent, FavoriteComponent] 
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

Also I didn't have a capitalized c on onClick() in the favorite.components.ts file.

favorite.component.ts :

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'favorite',
    template: `    
 <i 
        class="glyphicon"
        [class.glyphicon-star-empty]="!isFavorite"
        [class.glyphicon-star]="isFavorite"
        (click)="onClick()">
    </i>
    `
})
export class FavoriteComponent { 
    isFavorite = false;

    onClick(){
        this.isFavorite = !this.isFavorite;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap it in `a` tag and move the click event to it:

```js
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'favorite',
    template: `
    <a (click)="onClick()">
        <i 
            class="glyphicon"
            [class.glyphicon-star-empty]="!isFavorite"
            [class.glyphicon-star]="isFavorite"
            >
        </i>
    </a>
    `
})
export class FavoriteComponent { 
    isFavorite = false;

    onClick() {
        this.isFavorite = !this.isFavorite;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! but the glyphicon is not showing up at all ?

Comment: sorry, had some missing double quotes

Comment: no worries, not working.  not displaying anything just <favorite></favorite> in the console browser in chrome

Comment: you should move to the latest angular version otherwise it'll be really hard to say why are you getting errors.

Answer (score 1):

try this.

Remove the extra double quote '"',

```
<i 
    class="glyphicon"
    [class.glyphicon-star-empty] ="!isFavorite"
    [class.glyphicon-star]="isFavorite"
    (click)="onClick()">
</i>
```

if not working, try following

```
<i class="glyphicon" [ngClass]="{'glyphicon-star-empty':!isFavorite,'glyphicon-star':isFavorite}"
    (click)="onClick()">
</i>
```

Comment: im not getting anything on the main page to begin with, i think there might be a problem with '<favorite></favorite>'

Answer (score 1):

Please note that JavaScript identifiers are case-sensitive.

Your  component template has (click)="onClick()" but the component class defines onclick() { ... }.

Also try structuring a bit the code as the app folder holds all the files and is difficult to follow.
Check the official style guide: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html#!#04-04

Comment: yes its a bit confusing starting out.  I tried onclick but no luck.

Comment: I see that you are using an older version of Angular2 (beta7).
Is this the thing you are trying to achieve? Starting with a beta version?
Currently the Angular v4 is already released -
 http://angularjs.blogspot.ro/2017/03/angular-400-now-available.html

Comment: If your purpose is to start a project based on Angular2 I think the best would be to use Angular CLI which has it this time version 1.0 which is stable - https://github.com/angular/angular-cli
This is a command-line tool which will speed up your development.

Comment: So you can:
1) install Angular CLI - npm install -g @angular/cli; 
2) create a new project - ng new Angular2withTypeScript; 
3) copy all your files to the newly app directory or use ng generate ... to start generating new components, services, ...; 
4) finally when all is done start the development server - ng serve - this will be available at http://localhost:4200 if not configured in any other way;

Answer (score 1):

if i would have chance i do this in following way

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'favorite',
    template: `
    <a (click)="onClick()">
        <i class="glyphicon" *ngIf="isFavorite" [ngClass]="glyphicon-star">
        </i>

         <i class="glyphicon" *ngIf="!isFavorite" [ngClass]="glyphicon-star-empty">
        </i>
    </a>
    `
})
export class FavoriteComponent { 
    isFavorite = false;

    onClick() {
        this.isFavorite = !this.isFavorite;
    }
}
```

Comment: its not working.  I have another angular file called app.component.ts which loads up the favorite.components.ts but nothing is display on screen - only <favorite></favorite> in view source